# How to set thousands separator in R?

Tags: r, separator

Anybody knows how to set thousands separator in R?
I would like to get in output sth like that:

```
123 425 231
```

or

```
123.425.231
```

instead of:

```
123425231
```

Thanks.

Comment: At least don't use points, they are the standard way in R for indicating decimals.

Comment: find this post for more answers for your question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838774/comma-separator-for-numbers-in-r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
x <- 123456789101112 
formatC(x, format="f", big.mark = ",", digits=0)
#[1] "123,456,789,101,112"
```

Of course you can change the entry of "big.mark" as you like, e.g., replace it with a whitespace.

Comment: Thank You. Its simple and convenient solution but it doesnt worksfor large numbers (with >11 digits).

Comment: @MariuszLiksza  You can try by changing to `format='f'`

Comment: @MariuszLiksza Please check the edited version. For large integers it is better to convert to floating points with `format="f"`, as I originally posted and as suggested by @akrun.

Comment: If you want to use 64 bit integers you need to use other packages. There are several such packages, and the loss of accuracy with integers larger than 16 digits is neither related to your question nor to the answer (the accuracy is lost anyway, with or without the separators).

Comment: Thanks but sometimes R output wrong number in the end.  
For instance: > `formatC(123456789101114354 , format="f", big.mark = ",",digits=0)`
output > `352` in the end.

Comment: @RHertel Thank You! I didnt know that.

Answer (score 5):

Through regex,

```
gsub("(?!^)(?=(?:\\d{3})+$)", ".", '53332', perl=T)
# [1] "53.332"
gsub("(?!^)(?=(?:\\d{3})+$)", ".", '533382', perl=T)
# [1] "533.382"
gsub("(?!^)(?=(?:\\d{3})+$)", ".", '5333829', perl=T)
# [1] "5.333.829"
gsub("(?!^)(?=(?:\\d{3})+$)", ",", '5333829', perl=T)
# [1] "5,333,829"
```