# R large numbers in output are hard to read

Tags: r

I am working with US population numbers and I am seeing means that look like 2001234 and sd that looks like 22211121 and it's hard to eyeball what the numbers are saying. Is there a way to ask R to change the default output format for the console or reports to be 2,001,234 etc? Or 2.001M?

I am working interactively with the R Shell so defining extra functions to do this is not so convenient. I would like to change the default.

Comment: You could write your own `print()` method and stick it in your `.Rprofile`

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838774/comma-separator-for-numbers-in-r) doesn't help?

Comment: NB: I am a newbie still going through tutorials etc. I was looking for a way that would set a session default so that whenever I get output to the console it looks legible. In both your notes it seems to require defining my own function. Although I didn't know about .Rprofile. Will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for session options, try

```
options(scipen = -3, digits =3)
```

`1234567` becomes `1.2e+6` or 1.2 million

`12345678` becomes `1.2e+7` or 12 million

Its not commas or `M` suffix, its scientific notation, which is probably easier to read than the default you are facing, and its in options.