# Convert Numbers with Comma (,) separation R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have dataframe which looks like:

```
Var1    Var2      Var3     Var4
A       100000    5000     15000
B       1000000   2500     200
```

I want to convert them as below mentioned dataframe.

Required Output:

```
Var1    Var2        Var3     Var4
A       1,00,000    5,000     15,000
B       10,00,000   2,500     200
```

Comment: I think that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838774/comma-separator-for-numbers-in-r) might be the answer

Comment: Are you sure about Var2 output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `prettyNum` function :

```
prettyNum("100000",big.interval = 3,  big.mark = ",")
[1] "100,000"
```

To do this conversion data-frame-wide, you can go for :

```
library(purrr)
map_df(a, prettyNum ,big.interval = 3,  big.mark = ",")
# A tibble: 2 x 4
Var1  Var2      Var3  Var4  
<chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr> 
1 A     100,000   5,000 15,000
2 B     1,000,000 2,500 200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `comma` from the `scales` package to convert to commas. To run on all columns on the dataframe we can wrap it in an sapply function:

```
sapply(df, function(x) scales::comma(x)) 

     Var1 Var2        Var3    Var4    
[1,] "A"  "100,000"   "5,000" "15,000"
[2,] "B"  "1,000,000" "2,500" "200"
```