# Format numbers in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with numbers. I need to format it by adding commas.

```
df
ColA   ColB
sd     68900744.0
fg     78900744.0
gh     88900744.0
fg     1375292.0
```

Expected output

```
df
ColA   ColB
sd     68,900,744
fg     78,900,744
gh     88,900,744
fg     1,375,292
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838774/comma-separator-for-numbers-in-r

Answer (score 0):

For more information see `?formatC`

```
  df$ColB_new <- formatC(df$ColB, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=0)
```

for alternative options see [Format number in R with both comma thousands separator and specified decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals) or [Comma separator for numbers in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838774/comma-separator-for-numbers-in-r)

Comment: thanks. But it is converting numeric to character? Is it not possible to keep as numeric only?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I need to sum as well. And also I need to show with commas

Comment: You can do your computation and just change it for the final output. Maybe try custom print function: `my_print <- function(dta){dta$ColB <- formatC(...); 
print(dta)}`